# ExactTarget - How to obtain all tracking data for a list of subscribers...

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm attempting to get all the subscribers and subscriber tracking data for a given account using the SOAP service.

1. iterating over the stacks to find the correct stack with the username/pw.
2. method: `fetch` the `subscribers` object.
3. pass the subscriber keys into method: **ABC** and object: **XYZ**

Can you help me define **ABC** and **XYZ**?

Comment: Could you be more specific about which tracking events you're looking for?  You cannot just query for "tracking event" per se, but you could get "opens", "clicks", "unsubscribes" etc.

Comment: @Timothy great question! I would like "opens" and "clicks"...

Comment: @Timothy can you show me the list of events related to a subscriber?

Comment: This link has a pretty good list: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/eventtype/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer your question, I've attached a sample SOAP envelope for subscribers, clicks, and opens.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">hxvn5eq6wgetnffjmn9g4upg</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
          <!-- Retrieving Subscribers after Create Date -->

        <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailTypePreference</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>

     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">hs828jcnjkwq2bhkve3j4va3</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
        <Properties>BatchID</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EventType</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>URL</Properties>
        <ObjectType>ClickEvent</ObjectType>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">ktq8ttvmkedw4pvm93s8v3vg</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>OpenEvent</ObjectType>

        <Properties>BatchID</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EventType</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
      <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```